Upper and lower bounds to a non-convex problem; What if the gap in the solution is zero?
I am working on the application of relaxation of non-convex problems in game theory. I am dealing with the following optimization problem:
$$
\begin{align}
\max_{\theta_i, \beta_i} \quad & \min\left(\sum_i\sin^2(\theta_i), \sum_i\sin^2(\beta_i)\right)\\
& \text{s.t.} \quad \text{some constraints convex in the variables.} 
\end{align}
$$
My goal is to find lower and upper bounds to this problem. Writing it in epigraph form gives:
$$
\begin{align}
&\max_{\theta_i, \beta_i} \quad J\\
& \text{s.t.} \; \sum_i\sin^2(\theta_i) \geq J\\
 & \quad \sum_i\sin^2(\beta_i) \geq J\\
&\text{some constraints convex in the variables.} 
\end{align}
$$
So far what I did is to find over and under approximations for the first two constraints, which respectively leads to lower bound and upper-bounds to the problem. Suppose $\bar{J}^*_l$ and $\bar{J}^*_u$ are the optimal values of the lower and upper bound. Obviously I have $\bar{J}^*_l < J^* < \bar{J}^*_u$, where $J^*$ is the optimal value of the original problem. Now, what makes this interesting is that $x^*_l = x^*_u$, meaning that the optimal solutions to the lower and upper bound are the same ($x$ is the vector of $\theta$s and $\beta$s).
Now, my question is what can I infer from it? This is especially confusing to me since in fact I am not relaxing the feasible set, but the objective function. More specifically, the objective functions of the lower and upper bound problems (which I denoted by $\bar{J}_l$ and $\bar{J}_u$) are no longer the min of the two sums I had in the original problem. So, in fact I have $J(x^*_l) = J(x^*_u)$. Does this mean that $x^* = x^*_l = x^*_u$ is the solution to the problem? I can't see why!
I searched for this in Boyd and Vandenberghe book of Convex Optimization also in Numerical Optimization by Nocedal and Wright, but so far no luck. Clues and helps are appreciated. Thanks!

What do you mean by "So far what I did is to find over and under approximations for the first two constraints"?

@MarcDinh In the epigraph form, the first two constraints (the ones involving the sin squared terms) are making the problem non-convex. So, I started by approximating those. By under and over approximating the set corresponding to these constraints, I obtained lower and upper bounds respectively (i.e., made the feasible set smaller and larger, respectively).

"some constraints convex in the variables" can you explicitly list them out?

I am not sure to understand what you mean by under/over approximating an epigraph since an epigraph is a set to me. So I am going to answer with the idea that the under/over approximation thing is the following:

under-appoximating $\sum_i \sin^2(\theta_i) \geq J$ means that you have a function $f$ such that $\sum_i \sin^2(\theta_i) \geq f(\theta)$ and that you have replaced the original constraint by $f(\theta) \geq J$;
over-appoximating $\sum_i \sin^2(\theta_i) \geq J$ means that you have a function $g$ such that $g(\theta) \geq \sum_i \sin^2(\theta_i)$ and that you have replaced the original constraint by $g(\theta) \geq J$.

You have that
$$
  \left\{ (\theta,J) \ \left| \ f(\theta) \geq J \right. \right\} \subseteq \left\{ (\theta,J) \ \left| \ \sum_i \sin^2(\theta_i) \geq J \right. \right\} \subseteq \left\{ (\theta,J) \ \left| \ g(\theta) \geq J \right. \right\}
$$
so that under/over approximating actually means obtaining a sub/over-set of the epigraph.
If this is correct, then $\bar{J}_l^* = \bar{J}_u^*$ implies $J^*=\bar{J}_l^* = \bar{J}_u^*$ and a solution to your orignal problem is $x_u^*$. The important part is to ensure that the upper bound $\bar{J}_u^*$ is correctly computed; this will generally be the case if $g$ is concave.
